# Plotting live data using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I'm trying to plot the live data that I'm getting from my sensor. I want the graph to always update when new data is detected. This is my current code. I can't get the line to display.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
clear all;
S = serialport('COM5',115200);
temp =[];
accx=[];
accy=[];
accz=[];
i = 0;
while true
  if S.NumBytesAvailable > 0
     data = readline(S); 
     temp = [str2double(split(data,','))]; 
     accx = [accx;temp(1)];
     accy = [accy;temp(2)];
     accz = [accz;temp(3)];
     plot(i,temp(1))
     i=i+1;
 end
end
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Have you've been able to successfully retrieve and print the `temp` values in the while loop? If so you can use an `animatedLine` plot and the `addpoints()` function to update the graph upon each reading each sample.

Comment: I could retrieve the data just fine. I tried using 'animatedLine' and addpoints() however nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**May or may not be useful to solving the problem*

Given you can successfully retrieve the samples/values within the for-loop. Here is a playground script that adds values retrieved upon every iteration to a plot. This playground script adds a single value upon every loop within the while-loop. The `hold on` term is used to keep the existing plot and the new values on the same current axes, `gca`. If you retrieve multiple values on each iteration this script may require slight modifications. Here I slide the x-axis as the number of samples progresses, this isn't necessary but does kind of give an oscilloscope type feel.

### Snippet of Plotting:

[image: Snippet of Plotting]

---

Pressing the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> with your mouse cursor in the command window can be used to terminate the script.

### Playground Script:

```
clf;
%Initializing animated line plot%
Animated_Plot = animatedline;
Sample_Index = 1;

while true 
    %Retrieve sample (temp) value%
    temp = sin(0.2*Sample_Index);
    
    %Add points to the plot%
    hold on
    addpoints(Animated_Plot, Sample_Index, temp);
    drawnow
    
    %Window is the number of samples on screen/figure at a time%
    Window = 50;
    Sample_Chunk = floor(Sample_Index/Window);
    Maximum_Amplitude = 1;
    Minimum_Amplitude = -1.5;
    axis([Sample_Chunk*Window Sample_Chunk*Window+Window Minimum_Amplitude Maximum_Amplitude]);
    title("Plotting 50 Samples at a Time");
    xlabel("Sample Index"); ylabel("Amplitude");
    Sample_Index = Sample_Index + 1;
    grid on
end
```

---

### Full Script:

A full script might follow the lines of something like this. I have not tested this by reading a COM port yet:

```
clear all;
S = serialport('COM5',115200);
temp =[];
accx=[];
accy=[];
accz=[];

clf;
%Initializing animated line plot%
Animated_Plot = animatedline;
Sample_Index = 1;

while true 
  if S.NumBytesAvailable > 0
    
    data = readline(S); 
    temp = [str2double(split(data,','))]; 
    accx = [accx;temp(1)];
    accy = [accy;temp(2)];
    accz = [accz;temp(3)];

    %Add points to the plot%
    hold on
    addpoints(Animated_Plot, Sample_Index, temp(1));
    drawnow
    
    %Window is the number of samples on screen/figure at a time%
    Window = 50;
    Sample_Chunk = floor(Sample_Index/Window);
    Maximum_Amplitude = 1;
    Minimum_Amplitude = -1.5;
    axis([Sample_Chunk*Window Sample_Chunk*Window+Window Minimum_Amplitude Maximum_Amplitude]);
    title("Plotting 50 Samples at a Time");
    xlabel("Sample Index"); ylabel("Amplitude");
    Sample_Index = Sample_Index + 1;
    grid on
  end
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**